# Curl (7) error while import feeds data from audible

Tags: php, curl, drupal-7

I am not sure what do here:

I have a drupal site and am importing data from audible.com via feeds importer.  Set everything up a couple of weeks ago, info has imported without issue for the past two weeks.  I went in today do a fresh pull and when I click the import button, I got this message:

> cURL error (7) couldn't connect to host for
>   http://download.audible.com/affiliates/top200_thisweek.txt

I have not changed anything, but here is something I noticed and not sure how relevant it is.  I went back to audible.com to be sure the url had not changed, it is the same. I copied the url into my browser just as it appears above, data appears, but I did note that the url no longer had the `[http://]` in the prefix.

I then went back to my feeds importer, recopied the url into the appropriate field, the field sets everything to uppercase like this `[HTTP://DOWNLOAD.AUDIBLE.COM/AFFILIATES/TOP200_THISWEEK.TXT]` when I copy this in to my browser address bar, i get an xml files not not appear message.

Not sure where to turn - is this my hosting provider issue?  Audible?  Something that I need to adjust?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `http://download.audible.com/affiliates/top200_thisweek.txt` as your CURL URL.

And yes, ask your hosting provider. Most likely a firewall or DNS change on their end.

Comment: I don't have control of the field that takes this value, when you input the url, there is a function somewhere that caps everything.

Comment: left a message for my HP - but I will dig into drupal and try to locate the code for that field and turn off the function controlling the formatting.  Thanks for your insight guys.